# Barriers in java

Tags: java, c++, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

As in c++ when accessing `std::atomics` I can partially partially weaken order guarantees using `memory_order_acquire` or `memory_order_release` with `std::atomics::load()` and `std::atomics::store()`. Or using `std::memory_order_relaxed`

My question is: is this possible in java? I mean is there any barrier concept in java?

---

Please correct me if I'm thinking very wrong.

Comment: The JLS section on the Java memory model describes the behavior of Java memory "barriers": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) should have all the tools you need, including a CyclicBarrier and a Phaser (reusable barrier).

A correct memory order in Java is guaranteed at any call to a volatile variable, regarding anything that happened before. Since those barriers internally use volatile variables, the memory order is as well guaranteed after each `barrier.await()` call.

For a more fine-grain order, you need to use your own volatile variables, but given standard coding (read: not re-inventing the wheel, but using Java library), there is close to never a reason to actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java concurrency does allow a sort of latch or barrier. Look at [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

These both are created with a fixed number of threads in mind, passed as a constructor parameter. When enough threads `await()` this barrier then it will release for all threads.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have this right but a quick scan of [C++11 memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16179938/823393) suggests that you may be looking for:

```
volatile variable;
```

Please see [Volatile Vs Static in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2423622/823393) for a little more on `volatile` etc.

Comment: I's asking about relaxing order is possible or not in java

Comment: See [Instructions reordering in Java JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12554570/823393) - it is relaxed by default if the JVM wants to. It is **not** a simple issue.