# sprite moving on finger directions with velocity

Tags: android, andengine

I am working with andEngine the Open source game platform. I have a sprite that moves continuously on the screen and change direction when collides with screen boundary. Now, I wanna change its direction to the players touch point on the screen. I can't manage this part. I use **PhysicsHandler** to move the sprite with a velocity. I understand i have to implements **IOnSceneTouchListener**, to get touched point and set the direction on the sprite . But found nothing now. Here is my code goes:

```
Pilot aPilot;
PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;

    aPilot = new Pilot(222, 333, pilotTexures, vbom) {
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            /*
             * change direction when collides with boundary wall of Screen
             */
            if (this.mX < 0) {
                mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY);

            } else if (this.mX + this.getWidth() > ResourcesManager.CAMERA_WIDTH) {
                mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY);
            }

            if (this.mY < 0) {
                mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY);
            } else if (this.mY + this.getHeight() > ResourcesManager.CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
                mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY);
            }
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        }

    };
    /*
     * initialize mPhysicsHandler
     */
    mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(aPilot);
    registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
    mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY,
            AtomicEngine.DEMO_VELOCITY);
    attachChild(aPilot);
    aPilot.setScale(3f);
```

And my override **onSceneTouchEvent** method is like:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

        // need some idea here
    }else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Wait for your super knock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to calculate difference between the pilots current position (e.g. by calling `getSceneCenterCoordinates()` of your pilots sprite you get the coordinates in the scene) and the position of the the touch event - with that difference in mind, you can calculate the angle (measured on the [UnitCircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)) or use a factor that is a percentage between your max_velocity & distance length, then use your physicshandler and set a new velocity. the factor is used to limit the speed to a max speed.

so, your code should look like something like this (didn't test, ask if it didn't work)

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    MainActivity.this.mCamera.convertCameraSceneToSceneTouchEvent(touchEvent);//see edit
    float touchX = touchEvent.getX();
    float touchY = touchEvent.getY();
    float[] pilotCoord = aPilot.getEntity.getSceneCenterCoordinates();
    float pilotX = pilotCoord[0];
    float pilotY = pilotCoord[1];
    float xDiff = touchX - pilotX;
    float yDiff = touchY - pilotY; // could be wrong with AnchorCenter branch

    // use the max velo divided by the distance to get the velo factor for x & y, 
    // but perhaps calculating angles is faster, dunno
    float veloFactor = MAX_VELO/sqrt(xDiff^2 + yDiff^2); 
    float xVelo = xDiff*veloFactor;
    float yVelo = yDiff*veloFactor;
    mPhysicshandler.setVelocityX(xVelo);
    mPhysicshandler.setVelocityY(yVelo);
    return true;
}
```

so far the calculation for setting the velocity into the direction of the finger. if you want some kind of (de)acceleration (like: as long as the finger is down, the pilot (de)accelerates into the direction of the finger, else he will stick with his speed, you have to `setLinearVelocity(xVelo, yVelo)` instead and set the current velocity as velocity (to maintain speed)

**Edit**

The conversion of the touchEvent from a CameraScene to a SceneTouchEvent is only usefull if you add your `onSceneTouchListener` to your HUD. it converts the events x/y values based on the current camera position (over the scene) to xy-values as they would have occured on the scene.

else, if you add the listener directly to your Scene, you don't need to convert the touch event and the line could be deleted.

Comment: thanks for reply.Can get 
MainActivity.this.mCamera.convertCameraSceneToSceneTouchEvent(touchEvent); this line.

Comment: @shihab_returns see my edit, the line is probably useless for you, as long as you don't use a HUD and add the listener to your scene instead of a hud ;-)

Comment: yeah it works!Now wanna move the direction/angle  of sprite. Does i have to find slope of two points and setRotation(angle)?

Comment: @shihab_returns you could either use `PhysicsHandler.setAngularVelocity(float radian)` until the body/sprite has the correct rotation (this will result in a smooth rotating movement) or you use `body.setTransform(position, radians)` to instantly move the body to the angle you want. the angle itself should be calculated with `Math.atan2(yDiff/xDiff)`, to use float values without casting you can use the `MathUtils.atan2(yDiff/xDiff)` directly from the andengine package.

Comment: when i use PhysicsHandler.setAngularVelocity(float radian) but it rotates continuously.why?

Comment: ah, my mistake: you don't need to set the radian, you set a velocity. it's like giving a carussel a rotation velocity by rotating it. since you don't want to rotate it forever, you'll have to set the angularVelocity until it reaches the desired angle and then you have to negate it. it's probably easier to work with the body.setTransform at first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33080/discussion-between-shihab-returns-and-christian-r)

Comment: You should not assign that many new variables in `onSceneTouchEvent()`, which is called at least 3 times for every touch and even dozens of times when moving the finger, should you?

Comment: hey marco, at first this is imho an example of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) and the earliest point to take a deeper look into it, is when you either have lag during touch (due to allocation) or have lots of garbage collection going on. 2nd(and as argument against the GC): performance is almost always a fight against the GC. since [local variables are stored on the stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061587/java-memory-stack-allocation-for-local-variables), dealloc is kind of free and the GC never runs against it.