# Recursion depth - tabs & dents in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tabs, formatting

I want to format my output of a Java program so that I can see "how deep" the recursion is. How to do it?
It is really important not to get lost in my recursion tree.

Example output (trivial recursion function for counting the nth number from 0):

```
This is the first recursive call. Input value: 3.
    This is the second recursive call. Input value: 2.
        This is the 3rd recursive call. Input value: 1.
        Output value : 1.
    This is again the second recursive call. Input value: 2.
    Output value : 1 + 1.
This is again the first recursive call. Input value: 3.
Output value : 1 + 1 + 1.
```

Comment: The easiest (if not cleanest) way would be to simply add `int depth` as a parameter to your recursive method, and increment it when your method calls itself.  You can then use that to figure out how many tabs to prepend onto your output string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable (like `level`) that represents how deep you are. It starts at 1 and it increments at each recursive call.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    function(3, 1);
}

public static String function(int input, int level) {
    String tab = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++) {
        tab += "\t";
    }
    System.out.println(tab + "This is the " + level + " recursive call. Input value: " + input);
    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println(tab + "Output value: 1");
        return "1";
    }
    String output = function(input - 1, level + 1);
    System.out.println(tab + "This is again the " + level + " recursive call. Input value: " + input);
    System.out.println(tab + "Output value: " + output + " + 1");
    return output + " + 1";
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be clear and all right... but do I really have to use another variable (in the case above: int level)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use another variable ? Is it because of memory cost ? If so, one integer (primitive type) will not be of any harm. It has the benefit of encapsulating the depth of your recursive calls.

Comment: Because (and only because) they are always asking for the simplest solutions during interviews, but your solution seams already clear & simple enough.

Comment: I'm only wondering whether the level of recursion (int level in your code) is not stored somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean by "stored somewhere else" ?

Comment: 1. Don't now. BUT... 2. During runtime when there are 3 different values assigned to the level variable each one for a different recursive call... Java somehow knows that those values are only "valid" within different calls of the function and it is crystal clear to which call they belong to.

Comment: Each invocation to the method will add a stack frame to the current stack. Local variables of the function are stored on this stack frame. The `level` variable does not have three different values at runtime : there are three `level` variables stored into the three stackframes. Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061692/1743880

Comment: Thank you. To wrap up... Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Look at the code I wrote : it is possible to keep track of the depth of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using System.out.println, than you should be able to use "\tThis is the..." to indent the line on most java output windows. I don't understand if this is what you're asking for though.

If you don't know which recursion you're in, than you'd have to crawl Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().

```
String s = "";
while(numRecursions --> 0) s += "\t";
System.out.println(s + "Something something something")
```

Again, if you don't have a numRecursions variable than you'd have to do something like this

```
    int numRecursions = 0;
    void a(){
        int temp = ++ numRecursions;
        String s = "";
        while(temp --> 0) s += "\t";
        System.out.println(s + "This is a recursion level");
        //code
        numRecursions--;
    }
```

Comment: The number of tabs should show how "deep" the recursion tree is.

Comment: Yeah, but technically how? That is my question. If you do not want to, you do not have to come up with a solution, give me just a few hints.

Answer (score 0):

In your output function include a prefix string argument.
Every time you call your function pass in prefix + "  ".
Example:

```
public void output(String prefix){
  // Whenever you print, start with prefix
  System.out.println(prefix + ...);

  // When you call your recursive method
  String childPrefix = prefix+"  ";
  output(childPrefix);
}
```