# Determine the nesting of pages on the site

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, jsoup

It is necessary to determine the level of nesting of pages in clicks from home page. How to do it right? I understand that all the pages from the site will get recursively.

The code will look like this:

```
public void getPageLinks(String URL) {
//4. Check if you have already crawled the URLs
//(we are intentionally not checking for duplicate content in this example)
    if (!links.contains(URL)) {
        try {
            //4. (i) If not add it to the index
            if (links.add(URL)) {
                System.out.println(URL);
            }

            //2. Fetch the HTML code
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

            //3. Parse the HTML to extract links to other URLs
            Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a[href]");

            //5. For each extracted URL... go back to Step 4.
            for (Element page : linksOnPage) {
                getPageLinks(page.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("For '" + URL + "': " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Only still there will be a check whether the link is a link to an external site, if so then you do not need to go to it.

Comment: So the question is how to get the level of recursion depth? If so, you could pass an additional int parameter, increase it when entering, decrease when leaving (compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507978/recursion-depth-tabs-dents-in-java). You could store the depths in a map using the url as key.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!