# How to avoid HTML spaces in td tags during web scraping through java

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping a website which stores the data in the csv. The code is working fine but the problem is all those place in HTML where &nbsp is using, code is putting 'Â'. To avoid this I have tried something (mentioned below in the code) but because of that code rewrites that data again. Now, what I actually want that 'Â' this should be removed without any disturbance in the data.

```
for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(" , ");
        sb.append(" \r\n ");
    }

    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Element tdElement2 = it.next();
        final String content;
        content = tdElement2.text().replace(",", "");
        //I added the following code to avoid that 'Â'
        final String content2;
        content2 = tdElement2.text().replace("\u00a0","");
        if (it2.hasNext()) {

            sb.append(formatData(content));
            sb.append(formatData(content2));
            sb.append("   ,   ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    sb.flush();
    sb.close();
}
```

What I understood that why it rewrites the data because of the `sb.append(formatData(content));` I am appending the whole data for two times that's why it is creating problem. So how can I manage both ',' and 'Â' at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the replacements on the modified string, then you only have to add content2.

```
String content = tdElement2.text().replace(",", "");
//I added the following code to avoid that 'Â'
String content2 = content.replace("\u00a0","");
if (it2.hasNext()) {
 sb.append(formatData(content2));
 sb.append("   ,   ");
}
```

You can also rewrite it as

```
String content2 = tdElement2.text().replace(",", "").replace("\u00a0","");
if (it2.hasNext()) {
 sb.append(formatData(content2)).append("   ,   ");
}
```

Comment: Also for reading pleasure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306862/does-using-final-for-variables-in-java-improve-garbage-collection Basically, your use of final is not needed, as strings are immutable anyways. It also doesn't bring any advantages in terms of garbage collection. It just adds clutter.  You are also not assigning code in that scope to override them, or can override them.