# Does the classic variable declare as final contain a different segment of memory than the non-final variable?

Tags: java, class, variables, final

Maybe it's simple questions, but I can't find an answer.

Does the classic variable declare as final contain a different segment of memory than the non-final variable?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? I've not come across the term "classic variable" before.

Comment: Like: what context? You can declare variables as fields, static fields, or as local thing within a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, speaking about a **local variable**, no on the basis of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067851/1758762):

> The truth is, there is no **final** modifier for local variables at the
>   bytecode level.

Comment: Who says he is talking about *local* variables?

Comment: @GhostCat The OP wrote:  "the classic variable". I think that is what he/she means by that.

Comment: That is an interpretation. Point is: the question is actually unclear.